# Problem with Utility Functions in Shopware 6

Tags: vue.js, shopware, shopware6

I am now at a point in my project where I would like to use helpers and have looked at this point:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/using-utils

I would like to have a helper that translates my snippets read from the database, and maybe a view more to make the project more overseeable (maybe there is an easier way, I needed quite a few functions to get the translation).

As the article says, I also looked at the Shopware object, but I don't know how I could access a function using this object.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation on [how to add snippets](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/adding-snippets) in the administration. You can use the [Vue I18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/started.html#html) plugin to translate snippets to the currently selected language automatically.

```js
this.$tc('swag-example.general.myCustomText')
// in the template: {{ $tc('swag-example.general.myCustomText') }}
```

The functions of the plugin are globally available in components. No need to use additional helpers.

For `snippet` entities you could inject the `snippetSetService` to fetch the translations by their key.

```js
Component.register('my-component', {
    template,

    inject: [
        'snippetSetService',
    ],

    methods: {
        async getSnippetTranslations(translationKey) {
            this.isLoading = true;

            const translations = await this.snippetSetService.getCustomList(1, 25, { translationKey });

            if (translations.total < 1) {
                return [];
            }

            return translations.data[translationKey];
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: I already know the solution from Shopware, but it didn't help me with what I needed. With me, customers have the option of creating a folder and entering a snippet name and then using the component <sw-snippet-field> to assign the texts for this snippet to the installed languages. So I use the Shopware snippet system myself and need the translations in my admin panel. But of course I thank you for a quick answer.

Comment: I see. You could use the `snippetSetService` to fetch the translations by the key of snippets. I updated my answer.